# Examples of $G_\delta$ sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, big-list, examples

Recall that a subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is a [$G_\delta$ subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CE%B4_set) if it can be written as a countable intersection of open sets. This notion is related to the Baire category theorem. Here are three examples of interesting sets that are 
$G_\delta$ sets.

- The set of continuity points of a function $f:X\rightarrow R$.

  The set of positively recurrent points of a continuous transformation $T: X \rightarrow X$. Recall that a point is recurrent if there exists some sequence $n_i\rightarrow \infty$ such that $T^{n_i}x \rightarrow x$.

  The set of transitive points of a continuous transformation $T: X \rightarrow X$. Recall that a point is transitive if its orbit $\{T^n(x)\}_{n\in Z}$ is dense in $X$.

Question :
Can you provide more examples of interesting $G_\delta$ sets ?

Comment: Natural examples of Borel class higher than $G_\delta$ or $F_\sigma$ would be equally interesting. The experts were old masters (like Kazimierz Kuratowski) about a hundred years ago or so.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński That would be nicer. That, and a list of examples of functions of Baire class three.

Comment: Perhaps you (Andreas) or @user6129 may post the extension question?

Answer (score 13):

The space of nowhere differentiable continuous functions $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, as a subspace of the space of all continuous functions under the sup-norm topology.

Comment: What a nice answer!

Comment: Also: in the Fréchet space $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the set of all functions that are nowhere analytic is a dense $G_\delta$, a result by Morgenstern.

Comment: I wonder why this was voted down?

Answer (score 10):

The set of oracles *A* (as elements of the product space $2^\omega$) such that $\mathrm P^A\ne\mathrm{NP}^A$. (This also works for nonequality of other oracle complexity classes.)

Comment: That's interesting.  Do you know a reference?

Comment: Not really, but it follows from the simple observation that it's a $\Pi^0_2(A)$-property: for every clocked poly-time oracle Turing machine $M$, there exists an input $x$ such that $M^A$ fails to correctly compute $x\stackrel?\in\mathrm{SAT}^A$.

Comment: Incidentally, the set is not $\Sigma^0_2(A)$, and this has a neat topological proof: since the set is invariant under a finite change of the oracle, and it's a nonempty proper subset of $2^\omega$, both the set and its complement have empty interior. Thus, if the set were $\Sigma^0_2(A)$, i.e., $F_\sigma$, then both the set and its complement would be meager, contradicting the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 10):

In the space of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (identified via characteristic functions with $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and topologized as the product of copies of the discrete 2-point space), the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is a $G_\delta$ set.  So is the set of those $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ for which $\sum_{n\in A}1/n$ diverges.  (The same goes with other sequences in place of $1/n$.)

Answer (score 7):

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. The set of points where $f'$ vanishes is a $G_\delta$.

Comment: This has a nice consequence: the set of all bounded functions $f'$ for which that set is dense is a Banach space under the uniform norm.

Answer (score 5):

Most mathematicians consider connected spaces that are not path-connected to be a pathology (and perhaps they are right). So, it may come as a surprise that most continua are actually not path-connected. The 
[pseudo-arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) is a non-degenerate (i.e. at least $2$ points), hereditarily indecomposable, chainable continuum. Chainable means that 
if $P$ is a pseudo-arc then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, $P$ is $\varepsilon$-close to an arc (i.e. a path). On the other hand being hereditarily indecomposable implies that the pseudo-arc is very much **not** path-connected: Each of its path-components is a singleton!

Bing has proved in *Concerning hereditarily indecomposable continua, Pacific J. Math. V.1,N.1(1951), 43-51* http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102613150 that 
(the pseudo-arc is unique up to a homeomorphism, and) 
for any Euclidean space or Hilbert space $E$ of dimension greater
than $1$ the collection of subcontinua of $E$ which are pseudo-arcs is 
a dense $G_\delta$ in the hyperspace of subcontinua of $E$.

W. Lewis later proved in *Most maps of the pseudo-arc are homeomorphisms, 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 91 (1984), no. 1, 147–154* http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1984-091-01/S0002-9939-1984-0735582-4/ that: 
If $M(P)$ is the space of maps of the pseudo-arc into itself with the sup metric,
then the subset $H(P)$ of maps of the pseudo-arc into itself which are homeomorphisms
onto their images is a dense $G_\delta$ in $M(P)$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example by Roman Sikorski:

$$(H\setminus\{\mathbf 0\})\,^\mathbb N$$

in $\ H=_{top} H\,^\mathbb N,\ $where $\ H\ $ is the countably-dimensional Hilbert space (you can have the Hilbert cube instead). Of course any metric space would do, but this one is universal for $G_\delta$-sets in the Sikorski's sense. This is just one of the double transfinite sequence of universal sets for all Borel classes. Sikorski called Borel classes additive and productive, so that--for instance--$G_\delta$ would be productive of class 1.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$ of all irrational numbers.

Comment: That's what @user6129 said in their ***Question*** (the $G_\delta$ of continuity points of the second Dirichlet function).

Answer (score 2):

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lebesgue measurable  set: then there exists a $G_\delta$ set $G\supset E$ such that $m(G\setminus E)=0.$

Comment: This is not an example, this is a theorem :-)

Comment: Actually it is an example, coming from some result, like everyone else here (the $G_\delta$  is not explicit though).

Comment: As long as we do not question the definition of the definition we are still in good shape.

Comment: Any way I look at it, this answer says that an example of a $G_\delta$ set is: all of them.

Comment: Say that given a concrete measurable set, there is a more or less concrete example of a $G_\delta$ cover of it. 

OK, not a big example, but the best ones were already gone.

Comment: I don't like it either.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the [example of @AndreasBlass](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57345/examples-of-g-delta-sets/57361#57361).

If $A$ is some finite set, then consider the space of all infinite sequences $A^{\mathbb N}$ with the product topology. Then certain sets of infinite sequences, called recognizable, could be described by Büchi automata. A recognizable set is a $G_{\delta}$-set if and only if it could be described by a deterministic Büchi automaton.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few $G_\delta$-sets related to measure theory.

Let $S$ be a $\sigma$-compact metric space
and denote by ${\cal M}(S)$ the set of Borel positive measures on $S$ endowed
with the weak topology. The following sets are $G_\delta$ sets:

- the set of non-atomic measures in ${\cal M}(S)$,
- the set of measures in ${\cal M}(S)$
  singular with respect to a given measure,
- the set of measures in ${\cal M}(S)$ whose support 
  contains a given closed set.

This leads to the following surprising theorem.
Let $U$ be an open subset of ${\bf R}^d$, 
then the set of singular continuous measures is a *dense* $G_\delta$ subset
of the set of ${\cal M}(U)$. (Lenz, Stollmann 2004).

There are related results in the theory of self-adjoint operators on a separable Hilbert space endowed with the strong resolvent topology. These are $G_\delta$ subsets:

- operators with no eigenvalues in a given closed subset of ${\bf R}$,
- operators with spectrum containing a given closed subset of ${\bf R}$,
- operators such that the spectral measure has no absolutely continuous component on a given open subset of ${\bf R}$.

This leads to the following result.
The set of self-adjoint operators with spectrum $[-1,1]$ 
and with purely singular continuous spectrum is a *dense* $G_\delta$  subset of the set of self-adjoint operators of norm $\leq 1$ on a separable Hilbert space, endowed with the strong topology.
This is a consequence of the Wonderland theorem of B. Simon, 1993.

Answer (score 1):

The set of $C^1$ diffeomorphisms of a compact manifold for which all periodic points are hyperbolic and their stable and unstable manifolds intersect transversely.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a metric space, $A \subset X$, and $f:A \to Y$ be continuous, where $Y$ is a complete metric space.  The $f$ extends to  $f^* : A^* \to Y$ for a $G_\delta$ subset 
$A^* \subset X$  s.t.
$A \subset A^* \subset \overline{A}$.  (Willard, Lemma 25.8)

Also, completely metrizable spaces are those which are $G_\delta$-sets in any metric space in which they are embedded.  More exhaustively,

$X$ is completely metrizable $\iff$ $X$ is a $G_\delta$ in its completion $\iff$ $X$ is a $G_\delta$ in every metric embedding $\iff$ $X$ is a $G_\delta$ in $\beta X$ $\iff$ $X$ is a $G_\delta$ whenever embedded densely in a Tychonoff space.  (Willard, Thm 24.13)

References are to the very best textbook I have ever seen on point set topology, 
Willard's *General Topology*, 1970.

(I was looking up the universal properties of completions for my number theory class, in order to avoid reinventing the house, when I came across these nice characterizations.)