# Logical complexity of hard functions conjectures

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, peano-arithmetic, bounded-arithmetic

Let $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be the following statements:

$\phi_1:$ There is a function $f:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}$ computable in $E$ that has circuit complexity $2^{\Omega(n)}$.

$\phi_2:$ There is a function $f:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}$ computable in $NE \cap CoNE$ that has $2^{\Omega(n)}$ hardness on average.

> Q1. Is there any $\Pi_2$ sentence $\psi$ in the language of arithmetic such that we can prove $\mathbb{N}\models \psi \leftrightarrow \phi_1$?
>
> Q2. Is there any $\Pi_2$ sentence $\psi$ in the language of arithmetic such that such that we can prove $\mathbb{N}\models \psi \leftrightarrow \phi_2$?

Actually, I want to know if these conjectures are $\Pi_2$ expressible like $P\not = NP$.

Comment: In $\mathbb N$? Of course. One of $\bot$ or $\top$ can be taken as $\phi_i$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: I edited my question. I need an explicit sentence $\psi$ such that we can prove it is equivalent to $\phi_1$ for example.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Are you sure $\phi_i$ is provable in $\mathbb N$?

Comment: @FanZheng $\mathbb N$ is a model, not a theory.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: There is a complete language $L\in E$ with respect to polynomial time reductions.  Let $\psi$ be the $\Pi_2$ statement "$\chi_L$ has circuit complexity $2^{\Omega(n)}$. Is $\psi$ equivalent to the $\phi_1$? I think this should work, but I'm not sure

Comment: That statement is not $\Pi_2$, but $\Sigma_2$ (just as the original expression): $$\exists n_0\exists \epsilon>0\,\forall n>n_0\text{$L_n$ requires circuits of size $\ge2^{\epsilon n}$}.$$ The two existential quantifiers are extremely important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As given, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are $\Sigma_2$.

They *cannot* be shown equivalent to $\Pi_2$ statements by any proof that *relativizes*. This follows by the same argument as in [Examples of $G_\delta$ sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57345/examples-of-g-delta-sets/57348#comment144034_57348) or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16644. We only need to know that the relativized statements are unaffected by a finite change of the oracle (which is obvious), and that either statement can be made true or false by relativization with suitable oracles:

- There are oracles $A$ such that $\mathrm{NEXP}^A=\mathrm{BPP}^A$, whence $\mathrm{NEXP}^A\subseteq \mathrm P^A/\mathrm{poly}$, which implies $\neg\phi_i^A$ for $i=1,2$. See e.g. http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2005/08/extreme-oracles.html.
- There are oracles $A$ such that some $\mathrm{NP}^A$-language needs relativized circuit size at least $2^{\alpha n}$, for some constant $\alpha>0$: see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759390256S. This implies $\phi_1^A$ and (using the Impagliazzo–Wigderson argument that worst-case and average-case complexity is equivalent for $\phi_1$) also $\phi_2^A$.

Comment: Why the following isn't equivalent to the $\phi_1$?
$$\forall c \forall \epsilon(0<\epsilon<1 \to \exists n\forall C(size(C)\leq 2^{cn^\epsilon}\to \text{$C$ does not compute $L_n$}))$$ for a complete language $L\in E$?

Comment: Imagine, for example, that the circuit complexity of $L_n$ is $2^{n/\log n}$. Then $\phi_1$ is false, but your formula is true.

Comment: does this mean that assuming $size_L(n)$ dominates all elementary functions that are dominated by every $2^{cn}$ does not imply $\phi_1$?

Comment: Also, is $$\forall c \forall \epsilon(0<\epsilon<1 \to \exists n\forall C(size(C)\leq 2^{cn^\epsilon}\to \text{$C$ does not compute $L_n$}))$$ sufficient for derandomizing $BPP$?

Comment: (2) I am not aware of any such result. (1) It does, as $\mathrm{size}_L(n)$ is itself elementary. (I assume you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELEMENTARY), not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). I also assume you refer to *eventual* domination, as otherwise it wouldn’t work at all.) This, however, gives a statement of even higher quantifier complexity: loosely written, $\forall f\,((\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists n_0\forall n\ge n_0\,f(n)\le2^{\epsilon n})\to\exists n_0\forall n\ge n_0\,s_L(n)\ge f(n))$. That’s $\Pi_4$.

Comment: I mean, I am not aware of any result that this assumption would derandomize BPP all the way down to P. It should, however, imply $\mathrm{BPP}\subseteq\mathrm{QP}$.

Comment: Doesn't  $\exists n_0 s_L(n_0) \geq f(n_0)$ work instead of $\exists n_0\forall n >n_0 s_L(n_0) \geq f(n_0)$ ?

Comment: On second thought, what I wrote earlier is not right. “$s_L(n)$ dominates all elementary functions that are dominated by every $2^{cn}$” is *weaker* than $\phi_1$. The correct equivalent is “$s_L(n)$ dominates all elementary functions that are infinitely often below any $2^{cn}$”. That is, $\forall f((\forall c>0\forall n_0\exists n\ge n_0\,f(n)\le2^{cn})\to\exists n_0\forall n\ge n_0\,s_L(n)\ge f(n))$. Yes, it is also equivalent if the last part is replaced with $\exists n_0\,s_L(n_0)\ge f(n_0)$. Either way, it is $\Pi_3$.

Comment: Oh, damn it. "$s_L(n)$ is infinitely often above etc."

Comment: I had been thinking about it. Your last comment solved my doubt. Because $$\psi(f) := \forall c >0 \forall n_0 \exists n \geq f(n) \leq 2^{cn}$$ is not in $\Sigma_1 \cup \Pi_1$ we can not reduce the complexity of the formula. So, the natural question is how much derandomization we can get if we assume $\Pi_2$ sentences like the one that I mentioned?